# Determining natural frequencies of a system

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential

A system with a small range of motion has a potential energy of U= $a\dot{θ}^2sin^2(θ)$ and kinetic energy of T=$bθ^4$, where a and b are known positive parameters. Is it possible to find the natural frequency of the system based on this information? I tried using methods like the energy method, but the resulting expression has trigonometric terms, derivatives of position, and other terms that make it difficult to simplify the expression in a form such as $m\ddot{x} + kx = 0$ to be able to find the natural frequencies. The correct answer is $w_n = \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$.

I tried to solve the problem using the energy method but am not sure how the resulting expression can be used to find the natural frequency as it is not similar to any general expression.

$d/dt(T+U) = d/dt(a\dot{θ}^2sin^2(θ)+bθ^4)$

$0 = 2a\dot{θ}\ddot{θ}sin^2(θ)+a\dot{θ}^2\ddot{θ}sin(2θ) + 4b\dot{θ}θ^3$

Using the small angle approximation,

$0 = 2a\dot{θ}\ddot{θ}(θ^2)+a\dot{θ}^2\ddot{θ}(2θ)+ 4b\dot{θ}θ^3$

$0 = 2a\ddot{θ}(θ)+a\dot{θ}\ddot{θ}(2)+ 4bθ^2$

Comment: You can roughly find it just using dimensional analysis: $a$ has dimension $ET^2$ and $b$ has dimension $E$ so $\sqrt{b/a}$ has dimension of frequency $1/T$ (and its the only combination among the parameters that gives this). What this tells us is that the frequency is some constant number times $\sqrt{b/a}$. If you want it exactly do the equation of motion ("small range" I guess means you can assume $\sin\theta \approx \theta$ for this)

Comment: Are you sure about the assignment of kinetic and potential energy? It would make more sense if they were switched. The Euler-Lagrange equations  should give $a\ddot θ\sin^2 θ=-\dot θ^2\sinθ\cosθ-2bθ^3$, if I got all the terms right.

Comment: So for small angles one can reduce this to $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(θ^2)+\frac{4b}{a}(θ^2)=0$. That $θ^2$ has frequency $2w_n$ does in general not imply that $θ$ has a base frequency $w_n$, while the reverse is often true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, those are correct kinetic and potential energy expressions according to the problem statement. When simplifying the equation with the small angle approximation, why can you assume $\dot{θ}$ is 0? And from the last equation can you infer that the natural frequency is sqrt(4b/a)?